# edit exploration package

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, overlay, rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i have tried editing the exploration package but failed . these are the following commands i tried after editing.

/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/exploration/explore$ cmake .

/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/exploration/explore$ rosmake

/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/exploration/explore$ make

now when i run the explore node (/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/exploration/explore/bin$ ./explore)   following error occurs

*** glibc detected *** ./explore: corrupted double-linked list: 0x0919d538 ***

i hope somebody will help.
thankyou

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59078/edit-exploration-package/) by [Xittx](https://answers.ros.org/users/4233/xittx/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2013-03-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You better use [overlays](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Overlays) instead of trying to change installed packages in place.

**EDIT**: (presuming you are on clean ROS installation)

After making overlay workspace with `sandbox` directory (as described above) do:

```
$ roscd && cd sandbox
```

Now you should be in `~/fuerte_workspace/sandbox` or wherever you have made overlay.

Next, download `exploration` stack sources:

```
$ svn co http://svn.code.sf.net/p/bosch-ros-pkg/code/trunk/stacks/exploration
```

Update `rosstack` and `rospack` cache:

```
$ rosstack profile && rospack profile
```

Make sure that overlaying stack is visible to ROS:

```
$ roscd explore
```

This command should bring you to `~/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/exploration`.

Now you can edit the sources.

To compile the whole stack:

```
$ rosmake exploration
```

And finally to run `explore` node:

```
$ rosrun explore explore
```

In general, it is not a good idea to run node executable directly. So always use `rosrun`.

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2013-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Xittx](https://answers.ros.org/users/4233/xittx/) on 2013-03-25**:
thanks for responding Boris. i have done what you said but still having the same problem.

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2013-03-25**:
Did you add overlay after clean installation of ROS? If not, reinstall ROS and try again.

**Comment by [Xittx](https://answers.ros.org/users/4233/xittx/) on 2013-03-26**:
yes i remove it using this command (sudo apt-get remove ros-fuerte-*) , reinstall ROS and add overlay but still having the same problem . i,m using fuerte in 12.04

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2013-03-26**:
Could you post the changes you made to original package?

**Comment by [Xittx](https://answers.ros.org/users/4233/xittx/) on 2013-03-27**:
the modified stack  compiled and run successfully in my friend,s laptop , may be a problem with OS. thanks for responding once again Boris. i have just printed a string in terminal just to check it